# Modifying a dict value referencing a variable in a while loop

Tags: python, dictionary, pointers

In Python 3.11, I would like to understand why when a value of my dictionary references a variable, this one is modified in a while loop but not as a value of my dictionary. Example :

```
my_variable = 0 
my_dict = {'offset' : my_variable}
i = 0

while i < 3:
    my_variable += 50
    print(f'my_variable = {my_variable}')
    print(f'my_dict['offset'] = {my_dict['offset']}')
    i += 1



>>> my_variable = 50
    my_dict['offset'] = 0
    my_variable = 100
    my_dict['offset'] = 0
    my_variable = 150
    my_dict['offset'] = 0
```

I found my error, I have to use :
`my_dict['offset'] += 50` instead of `my_variable += 50`

My question is "why does this work that way". Why when I modify the value of my variable, it does not apply to objects referencing it. I found this question on stackoverflow [Python, reference to variable in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776421/python-reference-to-variable-in-a-dictionary) but it seems that there is a lot of debate in comments and the answer is not extremely clear to me. Thanks to anyone who will take the time to reply or attach a url to a useful resource.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Integers are immutable. You're not modifying the integer itself, you're reassigning the variable with a different integer.

Comment: The dictionary doesn't contain a reference to the variable. It just contains the variable's value.

Comment: @JRiggles They mention that in the question.